# Mediaplayer seeking not correct in HTC

Tags: media-player, progress, seekbar, htc-android

I am working in an app with both recorder and player and 
it almost completed. In most of the devices Samsung,Motorolla,
Sony the app is so stable and working perfectly. When i tried it in htc 
I came across a serious issue.

When the audio starts playing am updating it to the seekbar. This works perfectly in all other devices, but
when it comes to `htc(Desire HD, Android 2.3.3)` the progess is moving faster and a lag there in mediaplayer playing. I serched a lot and read a lot of posts.
Is audio latency a problem in Android 2.3.3 or its a problem of htc. Do any one have idea about this? Can any one help me with a good clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settting the progressbar max to 500 and implemting this timer will solve the problem. I tried and it worked for me

```
    InsideMMduration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    amoungToupdate = InsideMMduration / 500;
    // TimerTask for updating the SeekBar while playing.
    task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Graphbar.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (playButtonState == MediaMode.PLAY) {
                            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                if (!(amoungToupdate
                                        * Graphbar.getProgress() >= InsideMMduration)) {
                                    int tempP = Graphbar.getProgress();
                                    tempP += 1;
                                    Graphbar.setProgress(tempP);
                                    enableRewindandForward();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0, amoungToupdate);
```